# Reopen the Boss Tickle question?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, trolling

Recently the question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99756/my-boss-tickled-me-what-should-i-do#99756 was asked.

However, it was quickly closed as off topic, as it was asking us to make a choice for the OP (the usual "Should I...?" question that is clearly off-topic).

I took a shot at editing, so it is actually answerable and does not ask for us to make a choice for the poster, without deviating from the original doubt the OP had. Also, removed some ambiguities regarding if it was indeed tickles or more a "stab", as the OP said, as these details could derail good answers to debate if it was or not tickles.

**Should it be reopened?**

*Edit:* Seems that the same user asked a new question, this one clearly a Toll one. This one is already been removed altogether.

*Edit 2:* Seems that this troll situation is suspiciously gaining momentum and it is being discussed on this [Question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/recent-string-of-trolling-questions/4840#4840)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have deleted this question, as it is without a doubt a question from a troll account.

Comment: Good shot........

Comment: Yes good shot, given he asked a new question that is even more Troll than this one

Comment: Now I'm disapointed I miss the fun...